# Cookie vs x-auth-token with application supporting both RESTful and web

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security, restful-authentication, spring-session

I'm writing an application that exposes some of the services through Web while the others as RESTful services and using ***Spring Security* & *Spring Session*** for authentication and session handling. would like to know if we need to support both ***cookie(SESSION)*** as well as ***x-auth-token*** or we can rid of cookie completely for the token header(knowing spring outofbox supports both based on content-negotiation)

Answer (score 4):

For web application you certainly need cookie support. Browser wouldn't be able to send back x-auth-token all by themselves (unlike they send across cookies with every request). Likewise for API, cookie is not the best option for multiple reasons.

If you want to support both, you should be writing a custom HttpSessionStrategy which should encapsulate one instance each of     CookieHttpSessionStrategy and HeaderHttpSessionStrategy. Based on your url pattern of the passed in HttpServletRequest object (presuming here that you have a deterministic pattern at least for the API part) you can delegate all the three calls from HttpSessionStrategy to appropriate nested object, either to HeaderHttpSessionStrategy (for API calls), or to CookieHttpSessionStrategy (for web browser calls). I am using something similar in my own setup and it's working fine for me for this purpose.

Hope it helps!!